# Opa / Opalang: Set or access Record field label with binding

Tags: opa

In javascript, it is possible to get or set values in an object using dot or square bracket notation, e.g in:

```
var a = {b: "c"};
alert(a.b);
alert(a["b"]);
```

both alerts produce the same result.

Is there any equivalent of this square bracket notation in Opa, so that you can set the label as well as the value of a record field with a binding?

I ask this as I have the following code in Opa:

```
(User.current_server_user, User.flower_hierarchy -> void) set_flower_hierarchy =

  function(current_user, flower_hierarchy) {

    match(current_user.user_data.cell) {

      case {none}: void

      case {some: cell}: {

        server_user_cell_data_opt = Cell.call(cell, {get})

        new_cell_data = match(server_user_cell_data_opt) {

          case {none}: {base_server_user_cell_data with ~flower_hierarchy}
          case {some: cell_data}: {cell_data with ~flower_hierarchy}

        }

        _ = Cell.call(cell, {set: some(new_cell_data)})
        void

      }

    }

  }
```

At the moment, I can't see any way of setting new_cell_data with values other than flower_hierarchy, without completely replicating the function to set the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

Opa and Javascript differ very much in philosophy.  Javascript is a dynamic language that does not offer type-safety. When you're doing something like `a[b]` it's up to you to ensure that field referred to variable `b` exists in object `a` or else you'll get `undefined`.

Opa on the other hand is type safe and makes sure that all expressions "make sense"; you don't have to worry about undefined values.

So short answer is: there's no `a[b]` in Opa.  However, I'm pretty confident that what you're trying to do can be expressed elegantly in the language.  Can you explain in words what do you want the `set_flower_hierarchy` function to do?  (it's not clear for me just looking at the snippet).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I can't divulge too much about my work for the moment, but without wanting to describe it as "elegant" (though the language certainly is), here is a more satisfactory way of expressing what I was trying to do.

Firstly, I needed to define a variant type containing the different values I want to set in the cell, so that it could be pattern-matched without the compiler complaining about unmet cases. In this case the additional value is called "dbid":

```
type User.set_server_user_cell_data =
  {User.flower_hierarchy flower_hierarchy} or
  {User.dbid dbid}
```

Then I needed a function to set the new record contained by the cell:

```
private (User.server_user_cell_data, User.set_server_user_cell_data
  -> User.server_user_cell_data) get_server_user_cell_data_record =

  function(cell_data, set_cell_data) {

    match(set_cell_data) {

      case {~flower_hierarchy}: {cell_data with ~flower_hierarchy}
      case {~dbid}: {cell_data with ~dbid}

    }

  }
```

The code from my original "set_flower_hierarchy" function could then be abstracted like this:

```
private (User.current_server_user, User.set_server_user_cell_data
  -> void) set_server_user_cell_field =

  function(current_user, field) {

    match(current_user.user_data.cell) {

      case {none}: void

      case {some: cell}: {

        server_user_cell_data_opt = Cell.call(cell, {get})

        new_cell_data = match(server_user_cell_data_opt) {

          case {none}:
            get_server_user_cell_data_record(base_server_user_cell_data, field)

          case {some: cell_data}: 
            get_server_user_cell_data_record(cell_data, field)

        }

        _ = Cell.call(cell, {set: some(new_cell_data)})
        void

      }

    }

  }
```